# Swift 4 push viewController instead of present

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, navigation

i have problem to display ViewController via push. I have This code which works fine with present. But i need to change it to push. I tried to use **self.navigationController?.pushViewController(slideMenuController, animated: true)** but this doesn't work for me.

```
func navToRecord() { 
    let mainViewController = kMainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NQTPrivateOfficeViewController") as! NQTPrivateOfficeViewController
    let leftViewController = kMainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "NQTLeftViewController") as! NQTLeftViewController

    let nc = odrexNavigation(rootViewController: mainViewController)

    let slideMenuController = EVTSlideMenuController(mainViewController: nc, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController)
    slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
    mainViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: NSLocalizedString("Завершить", comment: "finishOdrex"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(action))

    self.present(slideMenuController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: `self` in this case must be wrapped inside a `UINavigationController` in order to push onto the navigation stack, which it seems that it isn't

Comment: @Scriptable so how i can do that in code?

Comment: You need to have this VC inside a navigation controller in order for self.navigationController to be set. So `let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ThisViewController())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
let nav = UINavigationController(rootViewController: self)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = nav
nav.pushViewController(slideMenuController, animated: true)
```

BTW don't expect this line

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(slideMenuController, animated: true)
```

to function if the VC you execute it in isn't wrapped inside a navigationController , because **self.navigationController?**  will be **nil**

Answer (score 0):

A push transition is for pushing a view controller onto a navigation controller's stack. If the view controller from which you are running that code is not on a nav stack then `self.navigationController` will be nil, so the optional chaining call `self.navigationController?.pushViewController()` will fail and the line will be ignored.

You need to refactor your storyboard so that the view controller is embedded in a navigation controller. (As I recall there's an "embed in>Navigation Controller" menu item in Interface builder that will change your storyboard so that the selected view controller is the root view controller of a navigation controller.)

Answer (score 0):

self.nc.pushViewController(slideMenuController, animated: true)